# regex both numberic and numeric with one decimal place

Tags: python, regex

Using
https://regex101.com/r/ukjM5F/1

My regex is:

```
(?:'\d+[A-Za-z ]*)(\d+|\d+\.)
```

It uses the `g` (global) modifier.

How do I grab all the
10
12

As well as
2.5
3.5?

Right now I'm stuck on how to grab the first decimal place (eg. 2.5)

I'm matching against this example string:

```
['Table:     Waiter: kenny', 
 '======================================',
 '1      GRILLED AUSTRALIA ANGU    **29.00**',
 '----------------------------------',
 'TOTAL       29.00', 'CASH        29.00', 
 'CHANGE         0.00', 
 'Signature:__________________________', 
 'Thank you & see you again soon!']


 ['1      Carrot Cake                **2.50**',
  '----------------------------------', 
  'TOTAL        2.50', 'CASH         2.50',
  'CHANGE         0.00', 
  '====================================',
  'Thank You and',
  'See You Again!']

 ['Table:     Waiter: kenny', 
  '======================================',
  '1      SAUSAGE WRAPPED WITH B    **10.00**',
  '1      ESCARGOT WITH GARLIC H    **12.00**',
  '1      PAN SEARED FOIE GRAS      **15.00**',
  '1      SAUTE FIELD MUSHROOM W     **9.00**', 
  '1      CRISPY CHICKEN WINGS       **7.00**',
  '1      ONION RINGS                **6.00**',
  '----------------------------------',
  'TOTAL       59.00', 'CASH        59.00', 
  'CHANGE         0.00', 
  'Signature:__________________________',
  'Thank you & see you again soon!']


['1      Carrot Cake                **2.50**', 
'1      Chocolate Cake             **3.50**',
'----------------------------------', 
'TOTAL 
6.00', 'CASH                          
6.00', 'CHANGE         0.00', 
'===================================='
, 'Thank You and', 'See You Again!']
```

Comment: just the 10, 12, 2.5, and 3.5 or all the money values?

Comment: What's a "numberic" and how is different from "numeric"?

Comment: all the money values from X   ITEM (XX.XX) eg. 10, 12 , 2.5 etc; only the one in bracket

Comment: what about 9, 59, 15, etc?

Comment: i have edited the string as above. Those with ASTERISK"XX"ASTERISK are those that i want

Comment: Please do not make your question less comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `\d+[.]?\d*`

That matches all numbers with or without a decimal point

https://regex101.com/r/9UHCt4/1

But, probably even better would be not to try to use regexes for the bulk of your text processing. Because this is structured, you can use a regex to recognise the structure of the line, use splitting/awk to break it up into columns, and go from there.

Comment: does he want the number of items ordered too? eg the 1 in front of menu item?

Comment: @depperm Maybe. But the question doesn't ask for that, and you don't have to cram all your text processing into regexes.

Comment: GOT IT! ANSWERED THANKS BRO

Comment: @KaelTee Feel free to upvote and/or accept this answer.

Comment: DONEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

Answer (score 0):

You can use a non-capturing group: it is then simple to match a number with two decimal places:

```
(?:\d[\s\w]+?)(\d+\.\d\d)
```

https://regex101.com/r/ukjM5F/3

Comment: GOT IT! THANKS BROOOOOOOOOOOOOO

Answer (score 0):

To get only the price of a menu item use:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\s+)(\d+\.\d\d)(?:')
```

https://regex101.com/r/ukjM5F/5